# Typescript: Type narrowing on promises

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I'm trying to figure out how to use typeguards on promises based on parameters.

```
function request({ logic }: { logic: boolean }) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (l)
            resolve("something");
        resolve(1);
    });
}

request({ logic: true }).then(a => {
    a.length
})
```

In this example, I'd like to make sure that the typeof 'a' == 'string'. I tried writing some typeguards in `request` but their results get lost. I don't know if this is just a limitation of typescript or I just need to do some smart type casting or what.

This is a toy example of what I am actually trying to do, which is to make an async call whose result varies slightly based on some parameters. And I am loath to make another function just to cover an altered return type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typescript function overloading to the rescue:

```
function request(logic: true): Promise<string>;
function request(logic: false): Promise<number>;
function request(logic: boolean) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (logic) 
            resolve("something");
        resolve(1);
    });
}

request(true).then(a => {
    console.log(a.length); //<-- knows that a is a string
});

request(false).then(a => {
    console.log(a.length); //<-- error: prop 'length' does not exist on number
});
```

Typeguards are meant to be used in `if` statements.

**EDIT**

You would be surprised! Typescript supports overloading distinction based on fields too! Check the following code:

```
function request(opts: { logic: true }): Promise<string>;
function request(opts: { logic: false }): Promise<number>;
function request(opts: { logic: boolean }) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (opts.logic) 
            resolve("something");
        resolve(1);
    });
}


request({ logic: true }).then(a => {
    console.log(a.length); //<-- knows that a is a string
});

request({ logic: false }).then(a => {
    console.log(a.length); //<-- error: prop length cannot be found on type number
});
```

**EDIT**

With a little generic magic you can achieve the desired behavior. This way only the `logic` field matters from the caller's point of view. Downside is that you loose typecheck even for `opts.logic` inside the `request` functions implementation.

```
function request<T extends { logic: true }>(opts: T): Promise<string>;
function request<T extends { logic: false }>(opts: T): Promise<number>;
function request(opts: any) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (opts.logic) 
            resolve("something");
        resolve(1);
        console.log(opts.anything);
    });
}

request({ logic: true, foo: 'bar' }).then(a => {
    console.log(a.length); //<-- knows that a is a string
});

request({ logic: false, foo: 'baz' }).then(a => {
    console.log(a.length); //<-- error: prop length cannot be found on type number
});
```

Comment: This should work, though my real scenario is a little bit more complicated. I am using named parameters. Can I have a signature like this: 
`function request({ logic: true }){ ... }`?

Comment: Nevermind, i was a little turned around. I will just use a slightly customized requestconfig type:

`
interface requestConfig {
  ..whatever
}
interface stringRequestConfig extends requestConfig {
  logic: true
}

function request(config: stringRequestConfig): Promise<string>;
`

Comment: Awesome! But how does it work if I don't want to have to specify all the other config parameters? Say i don't just have logic, but say: url, query, etc. That are all common to the config.

Comment: @PaulSachs I think it is a good practice to have all the fields specified, it has better completion and typecheck. Still can do although, see update

Comment: Looking good so far, I just need to deal with my setup has an intermediate function between the methods. I guess everything in between will also need overloaded definitions.

Answer (score -1):

Correct overloading is the next (should add  type):

```
function request(logic: boolean): Promise<string>;
function request(logic: boolean): Promise<number>;
function request(logic: boolean): Promise<any>;
function request(logic: boolean) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (logic) 
            resolve("something");
        resolve(1);
    });
}

request(true).then((a) => {
    console.log(a.length); //<-- knows that a is a string
});

request(false).then((a) => {
    console.log(a.length); //<-- error: prop 'length' does not exist on number
});
```